# High Current/Voltage will pull people

Tags: ac, safety

There is few questions about when someone touch the wire accidentally and can't get out from there.

1. Whether is high current will pull people or high voltage?
2. Is it only happen on AC?
3. What is the reason behind?

Comment: touch a strange circuit with the back of your finger, not the front

Answer (score 1):

High voltage leads to high current, so you can't separate them and AC and DC are just as deadly, whatever Edison and Tesla used to claim.

Current flow causes muscles to contract - that's how they work. Sometimes you get lucky and the path the current takes causes the right muscles to contract to throw you away from the source of the electricity, but usually the layout of the human body means that the reverse happens and you get more tightly attached to it, most often by closing your fingers around a wire.

Comment: 6mA is sufficient to cause hand muscles to contract and latch onto the conductor. If 6mA goes through your heart, it is enough to kill.

Answer (score 1):

1. High voltage.
2. No , DC is more dangerous , because there is no zero crossing , hence it is more difficult to de-attach.
3. human body has resistance , when voltage is applied , current pass through , only few hundred milli ampere will cause death

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is like electrical pressure, voltage causes charges to flow, and when charges flow through our bodies at more than a certain high rate, bad things happen. Voltage levels of 500 to 1000 volts tend to cause internal burns due to the large energy available from the source. As the voltage increases current increase only when the resistance of the body remains constant (from the basic law V = IR ). Under dry conditions, the resistance offered by the human body may be as high as 100,000 Ohms. So if the resistance of the body is less then even the small voltage also cannot be withstood by human.

Electricity which flows through human bodies is the charge, but it's not electrons. Instead, it's charged particles: potassium ions, sodium ions, chloride, etc. Since these particles are always inside our bodies, we can't say that "electricity" is dangerous. Instead, it is the FLOW of charges which causes problems.

In general for a normal human

1mA(mill Ampere) or (.001A) of current can be felt.

5mA of current can be painful

10–15mA, the person loses muscle control.

If it's above 50mA then it would fatal.

100mA above would be lethal.

Also if the voltage is DC then the above figures can be even lesser, because continuous direct current(DC) can harm more than alternating current(AC)

Comment: i have a high voltage dcdc which can generate 500V 2mA current, what happens only if 2mA passes through my body ?? at 500V ?, dont say i have to touch and see :p, i did not understand your statments, many a times i have catched a 20V dc supply, for that case all our electronic circuit are <50V and atleast 1A consumption why are they not killing us ?

Comment: In the case of higher Voltage like 500V or 1000V body resistance decreases because the outer skin is often punctured and the current travels in the moist inner tissue, which has much lower resistance.

Comment: Depending on how "conductive" you are at any one time, sometimes e.g. 50V might be quite safe and other times it may kill you.